# Using variables in Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing a file and looking in the lines for `username-#` where the username will change and there can be any number of digits `[0-9]` after the dash.

I have tried nearly every combination trying to use the variable `username` in the regular expression.

Am I even close with something like `re.compile('%s-\d*'%user)`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Working as it should:

```
>>> user = 'heinz'
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile('%s-\d*'%user)
>>> regex.match('heinz-1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2b27a18e3f38>
>>> regex.match('heinz-11')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2b27a2f7c030>
>>> regex.match('heinz-12345')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2b27a18e3f38>
>>> regex.match('foo-12345')
```

Comment: I feel really stupid now. So why is it that when I try and create it in a pdb break it gives me a syntaxerror

Comment: In the python debugger, it wouldn't let me create it as I was stepping through. Isn't the debugger a normal python interpreter? http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: WHat are you talking about? The code is copy-pasted from the interactive console? Are you trying to copy-pasted code in your debugger?

Comment: Make sure to use `re.escape()` as @Steven said in his answer. E.g. `regex = re.compile('%s-\d*'%re.escape(user))`.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the string using .format() method of string:

```
re.compile('{}-\d*'.format(user))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, concatenate the regex yourself, or use string formatting. But don't forget to use [re.escape()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) if your variable could contain characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
re.compile(user + '-\d*')
```